# Mysql Indexing Doesn't work On Single Group By

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have a query like below:

```
select s.org_id
     , s.report_date
     , s.country
     , sum(s.number_of_event) as numberOfEvent ...
     , (CASE ce.policy WHEN 1 then ce.custom_revenue else s.revenue END)
  from summary s 
  left join event ce  
    on ce.event_name = s.event_name 
   and s.account_id = ce.account_id 
   and s.app_id = ce.app_id 
 group 
    by s.org_id
     , s.report_date
     , s.country
```

And My indexes are:
For summary:

```
 1. index(org_id, report_date, country)
 2. index(account_id, app_id, event_name)
```

For event:

```
 1. index(account_id, app_id, event_name)
```

When I call sql query with explain command, it gives to me; "Using Temporary and Filesort"

How can I use indexes correctly for both tables?

Comment: What type of indexes? Just a stray observation: you have four columns used in the query from summary table that are not in your index...

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I'm lost.  Your `select` is only accessing records from `summary`.  Why are you doing a `join` at all?

Comment: My aim in here; To create a single index on summary table to contain for both left join and group by.

Comment: @Sha to avoid `using filesort` Specify `ORDER BY NULL` at the end of the `GROUP BY..`. Earlier versions of MySQL used to sort the dataset after `GROUP BY` operation. MySQL 8.0.x (some patch number) has fixed this anomaly. `Using temporary` is happening because of `Group By`, MySQL is first collecting all the data into a temporary table, and then aggregate it later. You can follow the Gordon's suggestion of using Correlated Subquery.

Comment: Show us the `EXPLAIN`; there is more info that we need to see.

Comment: The query seems to be an improper `GROUP BY` since there are columns not listed in the `GROUP BY`.  cf `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that you want to count the events in the `events` table.  That makes sense, although it is not what your query is doing.

If `(org_id, report_date, country)` is unique in `summary`, you might find that this is faster:

```
select s.org_id, s.report_date, s.country,
       (select count(*)
        from event e
        where ce.event_name = s.event_name and
              ce.account_id = s.account_id and
              ce.app_id = s.app_id 
       ) as numberOfEvent 
from summary s ;
```

In particular, you want an index on `event(event_name, account_id, app_id)`.

This eliminates the outer `group by`, which should be a performance win.

Comment: Gordon, thanks for your answer but I dont want to count event numbers. In here, I want to create an index to contain (left join and group by fields) on summary table.

Comment: @Sha . . . I don't think that is the question that you asked here.  Perhaps you should ask *another* question, clearer in its intent.